# SalesForce SOQL MALFORMED_QUERY errorCode

Tags: salesforce, soql

I tried to retrieve data through the Postman.
But I'm getting `MALFORMED_QUERY`

> ERROR at Row:1:Column:97
>   line 1:97 no viable alternative at character ' ' /services/data/v35.0/query?explain=SELECT AccountNumber,Id,Name,Phone FROM Account where LastModifiedDate >= 2018-03-19T12:55:52.000+0000 and LastModifiedDate <= 2018-03-31T12:55:52.000+0000

Answer (score 0):

No such column `AccountNumber` exists on entity `Account`. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name.

That is if there is a custom field called `AccountNumber`, then the query will be

```
SELECT AccountNumber__c, Id,Name,Phone, LastModifiedDate  FROM Account where LastModifiedDate >= 2018-03-19T12:55:52.000+0000 and LastModifiedDate <= 2018-03-31T12:55:52.000+0000
```